# Copy most recent file from a batch of alike files using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am not sure if this is possible or not. I am not even sure where to begin. I have a couple thousand files where the file names are named as so:

> nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.yyyyddmm.pdf (n = number, yyyy = year, dd = day, and mm = month).

Within these thousands of files, there are batches of alike files that have the same `nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn` part of the filename but the `.yyyyddmm` is different in order to represent the date of the file. (These batches of alike files will be merged together at a later point but that is not important to this scenario).

My question is, Is there a way to compare the `yyyyddmm` part of the alike files and have the most recent date files get copied to a different folder? I need the file that has the most recent date of the alike files on the filename get copied to a different folder.

The reason that I am having issues with this is because I am not sure if it is possible to compare parts of the filename to see which one is in fact the file that has the most recent date. I know that there is a way that this can be done through looking at the date modified date but this will not always give me the alike file with the most recent date.

Any thoughts?? Please let me know if I could provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to understand your problem/specs. Assume a loop over the files of your .pdf folder results in:

```
Looking at "0000000000012345.20120402.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012345.20120502.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012348.20121702.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012346.20120802.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012347.20121002.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012348.20121602.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012347.20121302.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012347.20121202.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012345.20120202.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012348.20121502.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012346.20120602.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012346.20120902.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012348.20121402.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012346.20120702.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012347.20121102.pdf"
Looking at "0000000000012345.20120302.pdf"
```

Would

```
Last file for 0000000000012345 is 0000000000012345.20120502.pdf
Last file for 0000000000012348 is 0000000000012348.20121702.pdf
Last file for 0000000000012346 is 0000000000012346.20120902.pdf
Last file for 0000000000012347 is 0000000000012347.20121302.pdf
```

identify the files to copy correctly? If yes, say so and I will post the code here.

First, you need a class to obtain and store the info put into the file names:

```
' cut & store info about file(names) like "0000000000012347.20121202.pdf"
Class cCut
  Private m_sN  ' complete file name
  Private m_sG  ' group/number prefix part
  Private m_dtF ' date part; converted to ease comparisons
  Public Function cut(reCut, sFiNa)
    Set cut = Me ' return self/this from function
    Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(sFiNa)
    If 1 = oMTS.Count Then
       m_sN  = sFiNa
       Dim oSM : Set oSM = oMTS(0).SubMatches
       m_sG  = oSM(0)
       m_dtF = DateSerial(oSM(1), oSM(3), oSM(2))
    Else
       ' Err.Raise
    End If
  End Function ' cut
  Public Property Get G() : G = m_sG  : End Property ' G
  Public Property Get D() : D = m_dtF : End Property ' D
  Public Property Get N() : N = m_sN  : End Property ' N
End Class ' cCut
```

Then just loop over the .Files and check the date parts for each group stored in a dictionary (number prefix part used as key):

```
  ' The one and only .pdf folder - no recursion into subfolders!
  Dim sTDir : sTDir     = "..\data\test"
  ' dictionary to store the last/most recently used file for each group
  Dim dicG  : Set dicG  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  ' RegExp to cut/parse file names like "0000000000012345.20120402.pdf"
  Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Pattern = "^(\d{16})\.(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.pdf$"
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In goFS.GetFolder(sTDir).Files
      WScript.Echo "Looking at", qq(oFile.Name)
      ' an oCut object for each file name
      Dim oCut : Set oCut = New cCut.cut(reCut, oFile.Name)
      If Not dicG.Exists(oCut.G) Then
         ' new group, first file, assume this is the latest
         Set dicG(oCut.G) = oCut
      Else
         ' found a better one for this group?
         If dicG(oCut.G).D < oCut.D Then Set dicG(oCut.G) = oCut
      End If
  Next
  WScript.Echo "-----------------------"
  Dim sG
  For Each sG In dicG.Keys
      WScript.Echo "Last file for", sG, "is", dicG(sG).N
  Next
```

**WRT comments:**

All my (ad hoc/proof of concept) scripts start with

```
Option Explicit
Dim goFS     : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
```

and contain some functions dealing with different aspects/stragegies for a solution to a common problem/topic. When I post code here, I copy/paste working/tested code out of the middle of a function frame like

```
' ============================================================================
goXPLLib.Add _
  "useDic02", "use a dictionary (Mark II)"
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' ============================================================================
Function useDic02()
  useDic02 = 1 ' assume error

  ' The one and only .pdf folder - no recursion into subfolders!
  ...
  Next

  useDic02 = 0 ' success
End Function ' useDic02
```

(yes, there is a first attempt function "useDic()" that was guilty of storing all the oCuts for each group to be processed in a second loop; yes, there is a function "createTestData()" I needed to set up/fill my TDir). Sometimes I'm sloppy and forget about **goFS**, please accept my apologies.

The variable names are part of an experiment. I used to advocate type-prefixed long variable names upto and including

```
Dim nIdx
For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aNames)
    aNames(nIdx) = ...
Next
```

Other people argued that nIdx-alikes variables just add some letters to mistype but no additional meaning over i, and that aNames-alikes can't be understood without the context and if you have that, aN would be a just as good remainder for "The first names of the kings of persia from the currently processed file to be compared to the names in the database".

So I thought: Given that there are 3 interesting aspects of a file name (full name to copy, number prefix to group, date part to compare/decide) and that there is half a screen between

```
  Private m_sN  ' complete file name
```

and

```
  Public Property Get N() : N = m_sN  : End Property ' N
```

and given that you need just those 3 properties of the Cut object to use it in

```
  Dim oCut : Set oCut = New cCut.cut(reCut, oFile.Name)
  If Not dicG.Exists(oCut.G) Then
     ' new group, first file, assume this is the latest
     Set dicG(oCut.G) = oCut
  Else
     ' found a better one for this group?
     If dicG(oCut.G).D < oCut.D Then Set dicG(oCut.G) = oCut
```

will the average short time memory cope with oCut.D?

**Obviously not.**

**To copy the selected files:**

Assuming you want the files copied to an existing folder "..\data\latest", use

```
goFS.CopyFile goFS.BuildPath(sTDir, dicG(sG).N), "..\data\latest\", True
```

instead of/in addition to the line

```
WScript.Echo "Last file for", sG, "is", dicG(sG).N
```

I did not anticipate that .CopyFile chokes on relative source pathes; so consider replacing the **N**ame property of the cCut class with a **P**ath property.

Trying to use

```
dicG(sG).Copy "..\data\latest\", True
```

results in:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'dicG(...).Copy'
```

because the objects stored aren't files (which have a .Copy method), but cCuts (which don't).

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for. I am really interested to see how this is handled.

Comment: +1 for the use of a class. But oh man, your variable naming. It took me multiple scrolls up and down to remap them in my head. Do you know we are allowed to use up to 40 characters for a variable as of the introduction of GW-BASIC? :)

Comment: Thanks for the script. Variables are a little difficult to map. I am getting an object error for goFS because it is not defined.

Comment: how should the goFS be defined to get the script to execute? This code is difficult for me to follow.

Comment: Wow that script runs like a charm!!!! Now if I wanted to copy each of the files stored in the dicG instead of displaying a message, how would that code look?? I have tried a few things and have been unsuccessful. This dictionary stuff is new to me and very confusing. Here is what I have tried the latest: Dim sG
      `Dim newpath: newpath = "newfolder"
      For Each sG In dicG.Keys
         dicG(sG).Copy newpath
      Next`

Comment: `Dim sG
     Dim newpath: newpath = "newfolder"
     For Each sG In dicG.Keys
        dicG(sG).Copy newpath
     Next`

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much for the help. I am going to have learn more about creating dictionaries. ALSO have to make sure to add the \ at the end of the file path for the copy or there will be permission issues. [link}(http://samuelhaddad.com/2009/06/26/vbscript-permission-denied-800a0046-solution/)Stupidest thing I have ever heard.

Answer (score 2):

How I would handle it:

1. I would make a dictionary with for each unique number part a separate key. The value will be an array with all file names sharing that key (and thus sharing the unique number part)
2. For each key in the dictionary, I will loop through the items in the array, searching for the most recent date.

Approach:

1. Get a file
2. Extract number part
3. See if a key for that number part exist. If not create a key for that number with an empty array as value
4. Add the filename as a new item to the array
5. Loop to 1. until all files are handled
6. Get a key
7. Get the first file in the attached array. Remember the date and the arrayindex
8. Get the next file, if the date is higher than the remembered date, update the date to this date and the arrayindex to this array index
9. Loop to 8. until the end of the array is reached
10. Store the file with the arrayindex as the most recent file for that unique number
11. loop to 6. until all keys are handled

Comment: +1 for the Dictionary; but if you are interested in 'limit items' (smallest, latest, ...) of a (structured) collection, you don't need to keep the candidates around - just compare/store/update the 'best so far'. Then you can solve the problem in one pass.

Comment: Yes, I agree about the one pass. Although it would make the explanation a bit more complicated as you do two things at once.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by creating a dictionary and a key? I know how to put items into an array.

Comment: A dictionary is like an array, but has unique keys (strings) as subscript instead of an integer. Just like an array, the value belonging to a key can also be an array. Also the interfacing of an dictionary is somewhat easier than with an array. How you can use an array can be read [all](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/dictionary.html) [over](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176993.aspx) [the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee784551(v=cs.10).aspx) [internet](http://www.google.nl/search?q=vbscript+dictionary+object)